# AWS Workspaces with NordVPN - Status Unhealthy

Tags: vpn, amazon-workspaces

I've got an AWS Workspace (Windows 10) running in N. Virginia and installed NordVPN on it.

I'm trying to use NordVPN to change my location so I can access certain geo-restricted websites in Chrome while on my Workspace.

When I turn on NordVPN and connect to Atlanta (for example), after a few minutes the Workspace status changes to "Unhealthy" and eventually disconnects automatically.

I believe this is because the AWS Workspaces monitoring service can no longer see my Workspace, and thinks it's offline or something.

I also tried to use NordVPN's "Split Tunnelling" feature to only protect traffic going through the Chrome Browser application, but as soon as I turn that on my Workspace is disconnected immediately requiring a reboot.

Is there any way I can configure my Workspace to allow the Workspace monitoring service to still reach my Workspace when the Workspace has a VPN connection? Or, has anyone been able to use a Workspace with NordVPN's Split Tunneling on the Chrome Browser application?

I also tried the NordVPN Chrome Extension, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks